# C++ sdk for surface 2.0

Tags: c++, sdk, pixelsense

I have a small application developed by me.
It is completely written in c++ and qt5.
I want to intergrate surface 2.0 touch api with it.

Basic googling says that this is not directly possible as you need to write in c# and call the dlls from c++ code.

Can anyone suggest how to start using c++ programming with surface 2.0 sdk.

Comment: Rats...no answer to this yet? We have an OpenGL-based touchscreen app written in C++, and would love to use the Surface SDK to enable multi-user gestures. Not sure how to, though.